# How do I access files installed with sudo apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, vim

I just installed Ubuntu a few days ago and I am trying to download and use VIM.

So I went to terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install vim`, and everything went fine with running the command, the only problem is that I can not for the life of me figure out how to actually run or even access the files that were downloaded.

So, how do I access the files installed with sudo apt-get install vim? Or an even shorter question: given my circumstances, how do I run vim?

Comment: Open up the terminal and type `vim` then press enter...

Comment: type vim foo.txt :)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have indicated, you should just be able to type `vim` or `vim filename.txt` and it should start for you.

As for the file(s), you should be able to see where Vim is located on your file system using the `which` command.  From there you can `ls` the locations to find the files.  On my system, I can track-down Vim like this:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
$ ls -al /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 19 18:10 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
$ ls -al /etc/alternatives/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov 19 18:10 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
$ ls -al /usr/bin/vim.basic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2015392 May  3  2012 /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Answer (score 1):

I love vim, but it is not the simplest thing to learn how to use. The default install is not very good either due to space considerations. Your `sudo apt-get install vim` is a good start to having a more usable install of vim.

```
vim
```

then `:help` will get you started. `which vim` shows as @BryceAtNetwork23 mentioned. To really learn try:

```
vimtutor
```

To see a list of all the files installed by any package use `dpkg -L vim-tiny`. To view a package and their dependencies use `apt-cache show vim-tiny`. I also recommend you install `sudo apt-get install vim-doc`, a suggested package but not a dependency so it's not installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$ which vim
```

to identify where vim has been installed into.

And use

```
$ vim
```

to open vim editor. If you want to know the parameters that you can pass type

```
$ vim -h
```

And also to edit a specific file or create a file in a particular file name, use

```
$ vim file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will show you all the files that were installed by a package.

```
$ dpkg-query -L vim
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/vim
/usr/share/bug/vim/presubj
/usr/share/bug/vim/script
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vim
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/vim
```

In this case, the executable is

```
/usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Or just `vim`, which calls `vim.basic`.

```
$ update-alternatives --list vim
/usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Comment: @bs7280 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)